# How to take a 5-day average around a specific date in r

Tags: r

So i have a dataset that looks like this but without weekends:

```
 X1          X2
3798 2009-12-29           0
3799 2009-12-30           0
3800 2009-12-31           0 
3802 2010-01-02           0
3803 2010-01-03         2.1
3804 2010-01-04           0
3805 2010-01-05           0
3806 2010-01-06           0
3807 2010-01-07           0
3808 2010-01-08           0
3809 2010-01-09           0
3810 2010-01-10         6.8
3811 2010-01-12           0
3812 2010-01-13           0
3813 2010-01-14        17.7
3814 2010-01-16           0
3815 2010-01-17           0
3816 2010-01-18         1.5
3817 2010-01-19           0
3818 2010-01-20           0
3819 2010-01-21           0
3820 2010-01-22           0
3821 2010-01-23           0
3822 2010-01-24           0
3823 2010-01-25           0
3824 2010-01-26           0
3825 2010-01-27         4.5
3826 2010-01-28           0
3827 2010-01-29           0
3828 2010-01-31           0
3829 2010-02-01           0
3830 2010-02-03           0
3831 2010-02-04           0
3832 2010-02-05           0
3833 2010-02-07           0
3834 2010-02-08           0
3835 2010-02-09         1.2
```

And i want to take a 5-day average around the 15th day of each month, and if the 15th happens on a weekend and doesn't exist in the dataset, i want to take a 5-day average around the closest date (14th or 16th), is that possible?

So this is the expected output

```
 X1          X2         5-day average
 1         2009-12-14           2
 2         2010-01-15           3 
 3         2010-02-15           4
 4         2010-03-16           2 
 5         2010-04-15           1
 6         2010-05-14           7
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what the expected results would be.  Could you show the expected output for this example data?

Comment: Hi akrun, i edited the post to add the expected output, i hope it's clear now.

Comment: my data is a bit different than this, but the idea is simple, i want to find a 5-day average around the 15th of each month, and if the 15th doesn't exist i want to find the 5-day average around the closest date to 15th

Comment: Al_Fawzan  Suppose if `df` is the dataset, because you mentioned about removing the weekends `indx <- !(weekdays(df$X1) %in% c('Saturday', 'Sunday'));df1 <- df[indx,]`.  Then my guess is that you need `rollapply` as shadow suggested.   `df1$rmmean <- with(df1, rollapply(X2, 5, mean, fill=NA))`.  In the current example, I have only one value that is close to 15h.  `2010-01-14 17.7  3.84`

Comment: Yes (rollapply) worked. But how can i extract the dates i need (15th or closest of each month)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy to take rolling averages with the `rollapply` function from `zoo`. Then you can just extract the ones you need (i.e. around the 15th of each month).

```
# packages used
require(data.table)
require(zoo)
# data preparation
df <- read.table(text=' X1          X2
                 3798 2009-12-29           0
                 3799 2009-12-30           0
                 3800 2009-12-31           0 
                 3802 2010-01-02           0
                 3803 2010-01-03         2.1
                 3804 2010-01-04           0
                 3805 2010-01-05           0
                 3806 2010-01-06           0
                 3807 2010-01-07           0
                 3808 2010-01-08           0
                 3809 2010-01-09           0
                 3810 2010-01-10         6.8
                 3811 2010-01-12           0
                 3812 2010-01-13           0
                 3813 2010-01-14        17.7
                 3814 2010-01-16           0
                 3815 2010-01-17           0
                 3816 2010-01-18         1.5
                 3817 2010-01-19           0
                 3818 2010-01-20           0
                 3819 2010-01-21           0
                 3820 2010-01-22           0
                 3821 2010-01-23           0
                 3822 2010-01-24           0
                 3823 2010-01-25           0
                 3824 2010-01-26           0
                 3825 2010-01-27         4.5
                 3826 2010-01-28           0
                 3827 2010-01-29           0
                 3828 2010-01-31           0
                 3829 2010-02-01           0
                 3830 2010-02-03           0
                 3831 2010-02-04           0
                 3832 2010-02-05           0
                 3833 2010-02-07           0
                 3834 2010-02-08           0
                 3835 2010-02-09         1.2', header=TRUE)
setDT(df)
df[, X1 <- as.Date(X1)]
setkey(df, X1)
# taking rolling averages
df[, rmean:=rollapply(X2, 5, mean, fill=NA)]
# extracting the rolling averages you need
dt <- df[, list(day15=abs(mday(X1)-15) == min(abs(mday(X1)-15)), X1, rmean), by=list(year(X1), month(X1))]
dt[day15==TRUE]
dt[day15==TRUE, .SD[1,] ,by=list(month, year)]
```

Comment: Thank you shadow, you are a life saver. The thing is i have a 10 years set of data (120 months) and while i got the rolling average bit ok. when i run the extracting code i only get one value for the first month of the first year. it should be 120 separate value